# How to save page properties using CSOM/JSOM/Rest api

Tags: 2013, 2010

I am updating the properties of page in sharepoint using CSOM

```
listItem.set_item('webPartProperties ',JSON.stringify(newProperty)); 
listItem.update(); 
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), 
                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

This updates the page properties whenever webpart property is saved (i call this function to do that)

But this does not saves the page property.

I have to manually goto, edit properties in page and click on the save button to save the updated field

Is there a way where i can save the page property using CSOM JSOM or any other client side script?

Comment: which page property do you mean?

Comment: pages in sharepoint.
i am saving all web part properties to a field in page in JSON format